# Display a Loading Overlay while MVC is loading the View

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an MVC Razor Site and want to display my loading.gif over the View while it is loading.
My setup looks like this:

- The **MainPage** is a Grid with Customers.
- When I click on a Customer in the Grid, I switch to **CustomerPage**.
- On the **CustomerPage** is another Grid which gets populated with their information

Currently it shows the loading overlay as soon as I click on the Customer in **MainPage** and only changes the View when everything has finished loading. I don't want that. It makes for a weird user experience. It needs to display the Grid on **CustomerPage** while it loads the information

This is the relevant part in my **_Layout.cshtml**:

```
<div loading-Overlay></div>
<div id="MainBody" ng-if="!isRouteLoading" ui-view="main">
    @RenderBody()
</div>
```

This is my loading overlay directive:

```
(function () {
"use strict";
angular
    .module("myApp")
    .directive("loadingOverlay", ["$http",
        function ($http) {
            return {
                restrict: "A",
                replace: true,
                templateUrl: "./Scripts/app/loading.overlay.html",
                scope: {},
                link: function (scope, element) {
                    scope.isLoading = function () {
                        return $http.pendingRequests.length > 0;
                    };
                    scope.$watch(scope.isLoading,
                        function (value) {
                            return value ? element.addClass("show") : element.removeClass("show");
                        });
                }
            };
        }]);

})();
```

Comment: You're setting `scope.isLoading` only one time, when directive is loaded. You need to watch this variable too (or just pls add a controller code).

Comment: I'm afraid I don't even know which part of the Controller Code you want to see. The guy who handled this project is gone and now I have to handle it (while learning both MVC & Angularjs as I go)

Comment: Ok, need to know, do you use "resolve" in routing code?

Comment: No. Our app.routes.js does not use resolve

Answer (score 0):

Ok. you need to $watch here:

```
scope.$watch(function() {
    return $http.pendingRequests.length > 0;
 }, function() {
    return value ? element.addClass("show") : element.removeClass("show");
 });
```

Comment: If I use this, the loading overlay does not show up at all :(

Comment: You're replaced all "link" code with my code, right?